# Styling Sharepoint 2013 Quick Launch Headers

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, css, content-editor-web-part, quick-launch

I have a very simple question.  I have spent hours combing the various solutions offered here and elsewhere on the web, but none of them work for me.

I'm simply looking to put some CSS in a Content Editor web part to make all quick launch headers bold font (not the sub-links).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the below CSS in Script Editor Web Part

```
<style>
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox > .ms-core-listMenu-root > LI > .ms-core-listMenu-item
{
font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
```

**[OutPut]**

[image]

---

**By the way,** the Content/Script Editor Web Part is not a solution to apply your CSS on all quick launch headers for all pages. It will be applied only on the current page that holds this Content/Script Editor Web Part.

So in case, you have `Publishing site` you can easily attach your CSS to your master page.

- Site Setting > Look and Feel  > Master Page.

[image]

Otherwise, you will need to edit your master page to add the CSS to be applied on all quick launch headers site.

Comment: Putting the .css into the page code works, but it gets stripped out when I save the page.  Do I need to enclose it with another class or tag to retain it after saving the page?  I can't edit the master pages and I don't want to convert my team site to a publishing site.

Comment: I am sorry I don't get your point , now it's worked but you face another issue, could you describe it in details?

Comment: I can see it works while in page edit mode.  But once I save the page, the .css gets stripped out of the page code - so it doesn't really work.

Comment: Problem solved - just add your .css code to a Script Editor web part instead of a Content Editor webpart and it works!  THANK YOU.

Comment: @Quasimodo Glad to hear it's worked, Please don't forget to **Mark** and **Upvote** the answer as accepted in case it helped you. thanks!